# The wp_enqueue_scripts hook doesn't work at all, not from plugin, not from the template, not for frontend, not for admin pages!

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I tried everything and my action hook wp_enqueue_scripts doesn't work! What can stop it from working? This is my code inside the plugin. The plugin is activated:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    error_log("try 9");
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts');
```

Comment: This `wp_enqueue_scripts` is for adding stylesheets or JavaScript files to the system. Why are you using this `error_log("try 9");` function here ?

Comment: I want to see if it is coming inside this function at all. Inside this function I want to load javascript files. But, this is not hapenning, because it is not going inside this function at all. Not from admin, not from a regular front end page (for a non-admin logged-in user).

Comment: You are enqueuing for the front and your code is correct, if your trying this for the admin area you will need to use admin_enqueue_scripts. I would deactivate plugins to see if this resolves your issue

Comment: I don't need it for admin, I need it for frontend page.

Comment: Deactivate your plugins also include a file and then use the console to check for either css files load or JavaScript if this works then start to activate plugins one at a time

Comment: Which console? I don't know about it.

Comment: If you right click on a page and select inspect element you will get a console this will have resources loaded like images , css , js and other features you can look in the css folder to see what ones have been included in your page

Comment: Things to test add this code <script src="whatever.js" type="text/javascript"></script> change link to your file this is not bet practice but will check that your not enqueuing wrong, in your js add alert('I am working'); if you get the alert pop up things are working you can then work on why your code is not working

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic does your theme call the `wp_head()` function? This is what invokes the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

Comment: @Milo wp_head(); solved the problem. Can you please make an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wp_enqueue_scripts` function is hooked to run on the [`wp_head` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/), which is triggered by the [`wp_head()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/).

This function should be placed within the `<head>` tag of your theme's markup.

If we refer to the core file [`default-filters.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L240), we can see the many functions that rely on `wp_head` for output.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to enqueue your scripts is the following:

```
function my_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script ('my-js','YOUR JS URL HERE');
    wp_enqueue_style ('my-style','YOUR CSS URL HERE');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts');
```

You are using the hook that fires when queuing scripts, but not queuing anything. Take a look into Codex to notice the difference between [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).

Also, the 5th argument of `wp_enqueue_script()` allows you to queue your script in the footer. If you have problem with yout `wp_head()` hook, try the footer:

`wp_enqueue_script ('my-js' , 'YOUR JS URL HERE' , '' , '' , true);`

This will queue your js file in the footer, which is required when you need the DOM to be ready for the js file to process.

Comment: yes, I know that I am not yet queueing the script, but I just want to go inside the function, and I am not getting in.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic So your function is not fired at all?! That's strange, and huge possibility is some plugin or theme is interfering.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can a theme or plugin interfere with this functionality, since it is basic native wordpress functionality? It can be the case though, since I am working on someone else's theme.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic Have you tried the usual disabling of plugins and switching to the default them to see which one is triggering the issue? That would narrow your possibilities by a great deal.